# How to fire Java method using bash

Tags: java, pid, signal-handling

Suppose I launch a Java application:

`java -cp whatever.jar com.example.Start`

Process launches ok and keeps running with PID 1314.

Now I would like the system to fire a method by users request.
**How can I use bash to signal the running PID and have it fire a method?**

Comment: Maybe the bash script can write to a file, which you java process can watch/poll.

Comment: @Scorpion that would work but it's not elegant at all.

Comment: yep, you are right but with java 7 watch service it is going to be easier to do and better in terms of performance. I am not sure if a bash script can be used to say send a message to the message queue because that is quite a standard approach to expose functions.

Answer (score 2):

My thought is to have bash echo data to the Java processes via a named pipe, which I'm pretty sure Java has support for.

Comment: Java does not, no its own, support Named pipes - it can read / write to them on Linux/Unix via the nio and io packages but it can't make them.

Comment: Ah, so the launch script would need to create the named pipe, then launch the Java app which would connect to it, and then a later bash script could interact with it via that named pipe. Cool.

Comment: Yeah, just mkfifo to make the named pipe... IIRC it'll be persistent so it shouldn't have to be re-made with each script invocation.. but you can use a little bash scripting to see if it exists and make it if not.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with a Java process, you would normally use RMI from another process (this could be in the same JAR)

However, if you want a pure bash/unix utilities solution, you could have the application listen on a port for commands and send back responses.  This means you could use plain telnet to send commands and get output.  One example of this is to use a `http` server with `wget` or you could have a simple socket based solution.